# Static linked openssl causes segfault in Qt application

Tags: c, qt, openssl

I have Qt 4.8 app which had been working fine so far. It dynamically links with system installed the Qt libs on Ubuntu and other Linux distro.

Recently, I added a `libcurl` dependency to my project, since I needed `https`, I statically compiled `libcurl` with `openssl 1.1.0h` support (to avoid openssl version lock). Now after linking `libcurl.a, libcrypto.a and libssl.a` with my app the curl functions work fine.

But the existing code which uses `QNetworkAccessManager` starting `seg faulting` suddenly. Following is the stacktrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x55) at malloc.c:2951
#1  0x00000000006916d4 in X509_VERIFY_PARAM_free ()
#2  0x00007fffca7e1ee9 in SSL_free ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00007ffff6e7fd54 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#4  0x00007ffff6e81627 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#5  0x00007ffff6e7889c in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#6  0x00007ffff6e7381d in QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#7  0x00007ffff6e09e53 in QNetworkRequest::sslConfiguration() const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#8  0x00007ffff6df2143 in QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation, QNetworkRequest const&, QIODevice*) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#9  0x00007ffff6deefc4 in QNetworkAccessManager::get(QNetworkRequest const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
```

Comment: Please try OpenSSL 1.0.1, it doesn't make sense, but it appears the statically linked 1.1.0h causes some trouble. Is there any chance Qt picks the 1.1.0 functions? Qt  supports OpenSSL 1.1.0 only above version 5.10 (linking OpenSSL statically is never a good idea, when critical patches are available people can't simply exchange the OpenSSL library)

Comment: The segfault is at a malloc though, so it may also be just a corrupted heap. Have you tried to run your code with asan?